# History of Ethereum

Tags: history

My son is writing a school project on the history of Ethereum and there are a few questions that he has that we've been unable to find online.  I wonder if anyone in  this community would be able to help?

We know the date of the genesis block, but would love to know who mined it (I know the first block is technically not mined, so who pressed "go") and where this happened.  My guess would be that it was Dr. Gavin Wood as the core C++ developer, based in London?  But, of course, I have nothing to substantiate that guess.

Is it also safe to say that the second block (block 1) was the first "mined" block?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody mined the genesis block, nobody pushed a button.

The genesis block with the exception of the extra data was defined several days before the launch. There's a repository with the python script used to generate the genesis block https://github.com/ethereum/genesis_block_generator.

The extra data was going to be the hash of block #1028201 on the Ethereum testnet. When the block arrived everyone was able to run the python script to calculate the genesis block and then start mining.

For more details read the official announcement [Final Steps](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/07/27/final-steps/).

There is a book *The Infinite Machine: How an Army of Crypto-hackers Is Building the Next Internet with Ethereum* by Camila Russo that contains more details about Ethereum creation and early days that your son might find interesting.

Comment: Thanks, that's great info.  And for the book recommendation too!